# is there a faster way for Training IsolationForest on each row of pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a Pandas DataFrame which contain transaction count of 2000 terminals for 30 days(columns are day of month) DataFrame looks like this:

```py
trx.head()
    TerminalID 8881 8882    8883    8884    8885    8886    ... 
0   11546   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 
1   200002  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 
2   200512  1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 ...
3   202630  3.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 ...
4   207000  2.0 4.0 1.0 6.0 3.0 7.0 ...
```

I want to use IsolationForest for anomaly detection on each row of my data.

First I convert each row to a new DataFrame and fit data on that, one by one for every row and I will add the the result to a list:

```py
def find_anomaly(trx1,outliers_fraction):
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    np_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(trx1)
    data = pd.DataFrame(np_scaled)
    # train isolation forest
    model =  IsolationForest(contamination=outliers_fraction)
    model.fit(data) 
    trx1['anomaly'] = pd.Series(model.predict(data))
    return(trx1)
#This for is slow
list_terminal_trx = []
for i in range(0,len(trx)-1):
    trx1=trx.iloc[i,1:].reset_index()
    trx1.columns=['day','count']
    trx1['day']=trx1['day'].astype(float)
    list_terminal_trx.append(find_anomaly(trx1,outliers_fraction))
    print('Learning for record',i)
```

The code above works fine but it is slow I wanted to know if there is a better way?

**Edited1:** thanks to [@AT_asks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11532266/at-asks) advise I set n_jobs=-1 and now It is faster But is there any alternative to my for loop?

**Edited2:** with some modification I used what [@AT_asks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11532266/at-asks) suggested to use apply() but I got no performance differences:
For version takes 3:29:00
Apply Version Takes 3:25:28

**Edited3:** using iterrows() instead of for brings the same result:
3min 16s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

Comment: Why are you training your model on each row? The examples I have seen train on the complete dataset

Comment: The example given here trains the model on the complete data: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_isolation_forest.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-ensemble-plot-isolation-forest-py

Comment: @ClockSlave Each row is a different Terminal (Merchant) With a different behavior  and pattern, consider each row as a different data series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might get some improvements if add this parameter

```
model =  IsolationForest(contamination=outliers_fraction, n_jobs=-1)
```

Also, we could try this.

```
# Do not create instance every time
scaler = StandardScaler()

def find_anomaly(trx1,outliers_fraction):    
    np_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(trx1)
    data = pd.DataFrame(np_scaled)
    # train isolation forest
    model =  IsolationForest(contamination=outliers_fraction, n_jobs=-1)
    model.fit(data) 
    trx1['anomaly'] = pd.Series(model.predict(data))
    return(trx1)

# not loop but apply
list_terminal_trx = trx.apply(lambda x: find_anomaly(x,outliers_fraction), axis =1).values
```

Comment: Thanks for your advise It is a lot faster But is there any alternative to my for loop?

Comment: Updated the solution. Could not try it with real data, but in theory, should work

Comment: when I use n_jobs=-1 with visual studio code Jupyter Server(python interactive window) it works fine but when I hit F5 (start debugging) It crashes.

Comment: with some modification I used apply() but I got no performance differences: For version takes 3:29:00 Apply Version Takes 3:25:28

Comment: You could try parallel apply 
https://towardsdatascience.com/pandaral-lel-a-simple-and-efficient-tool-to-parallelize-your-pandas-operations-on-all-your-cpus-bb5ff2a409ae

and/or
use pararameter for forest
warm_start=True